# Some questions on Android UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, appbar

Please, anybody help me. I have a 2 big problem:

1. App bar moves my left button to center app, right after string:
   *setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)*
   buttons - wrap/wrap, tryed to wrap her in RelativeLayout, tryed to set "anchor" parameter - no effect - title moves her then appears.
2. Fragments appears higher then fragmentContainer - on my appbar.

My idea was - 1 main activity + 3 fragments changes in her bottom part, and settings-activity. Screen applied.

Also I have a question:
For now I changes fragment using .replace - method. If I do it then I send search query and receive list of elements - it would create a new main fragment with empty list? But now it's not important. Of course, I can get fragments by tag, if one exists. [image: screen]

Code.
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    style="@style/match">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        style="@style/fill"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <RelativeLayout
                style="@style/wrap">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settings_btn"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/servis"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/settings.title"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logout_btn"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/off"
                android:contentDescription="@string/main.logout"
                android:cropToPadding="false"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/fill"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/search_tab"
                style="@style/wrap"
                android:text="@string/main.search"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/saved_tab"
                style="@style/wrap"
                android:text="@string/main.saved"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content.xml (like in books):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
style="@style/match"
tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity"/>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/match">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/audio_list"
    style="@style/recycler_view"/>

... <buttonsLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private DataManager mDataManager;

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ImageView mSettings, mLogout;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private TabItem mSearchTab, mSavedTab;
private int accentColorId, primaryColorId;

private String mQuery;

public void setQuery(String query) {
    mQuery = query;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDataManager = DataManager.getInstance();

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    //mToolbar.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    mSettings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_btn);
    mSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLogout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logout_btn);
    mLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

    accentColorId = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    primaryColorId = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mSearchTab = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.search_tab);
    mSavedTab = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.saved_tab);

    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                //mSearchTab.setBackgroundColor(accentColorId);
                //mSavedTab.setBackgroundColor(primaryColorId);
                showFragment(SearchFragment.newInstance(mQuery), "search");
            } else if(tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                showFragment(new SavedFragment(), "saved");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
    });
    mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    signIn();
}

...

private void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tag)
        .addToBackStack(tag)
        .commit();
}
```

Comment: Posted) All as I wrote higher.